# How to draw this picture (draw arrows in middle of a loop generated by 'control', make break ) using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-knots

[image: Picture]

I would like to draw this picture by [tikz]. The elliptic and circle are easy, and I use 'control' to draw the red loop. But I do not know how to draw the arrow in the middle of the loop and do not know how to make spaces in the intersections.

Here is my codes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) ellipse (20pt and 10pt);
\draw (1,0) ellipse (20pt and 20pt);
\filldraw [red] (1,-1.5) circle (1pt);
\draw[draw=red] (1,-1.5) .. controls (0.2,0.2) and (1.8,0.2).. (1,-1.5);
\draw[draw=red] (1,-1.5) .. controls (-0.5,0.6) and (-2,0.2) .. (1,-1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here is what I got

[image]

I try to use 'decoration', but it does not work well for 'control'.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What did you do so far? Can you provide us with some code? As for the intersections: It may be helpful to think about splitting the paths in half, and draw one half behind and the other before the other path. You could place a thicker white copy of the paths underneath for the gaps.

Comment: The breaks at the intersections are similar to knot diagrams, so I recommend looking at packages that draw knots.  There's a list at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17181/86 (I'd take note of the dates of the answers rather than the votes).

Comment: For the arrows, use the `markings` TikZ library to place the arrows at positions on the path.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Thank you and I will take a look at the breaks. But the 'marking' does not work well for my path generated by 'control'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an example using the [`knots`](https://ctan.org/pkg/spath3) library for the intersections and `decorations.markings` for the arrows.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/621085/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  knots,
  decorations.markings,
  arrows.meta
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{knot}[
%  draft mode=crossings,
  flip crossing/.list={6,4,1},
  end tolerance=12pt,
]
\strand (0,0) ellipse[x radius=20pt, y radius=10pt];
\strand (1,0) circle[radius=20pt];
\strand[
  draw=red,
  only when rendering/.style={
    postaction=decorate,
  },
  decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position .47 with {\arrowreversed{To}}
  }
] (1,-1.5) .. controls (0.2,0.2) and (1.8,0.2).. (1,-1.5);
\strand[
  draw=red,
  only when rendering/.style={
    postaction=decorate,
  },
  decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position .45 with {\arrow{To}}
  }
] (1,-1.5) .. controls (-0.5,0.6) and (-2,0.2) .. (1,-1.5);
\end{knot}
\filldraw [red] (1,-1.5) circle[radius=1pt];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: curves with arrows and gaps]

Comment: Thank you, I learnt a lot from it.

Answer (score 4):

Drawing arrows in the middle of a line is addressed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3172/125871). In the code below I defined the style `midarr` to place the arrow.

The `knots` library can be used as in Andrew Stacy's solution, but if you want to do this manually, you can use `double=<linecolor>` and `double distance=<linethickness>`. I defined a style `overcross` that will produce the desired effect:

```
\tikzset{overcross/.style={double, line width=1.5, white, double=#1, double distance=\knotwidth},
overcross/.default=black}
```

The macro `\knotwidth` can be set to the desired line thickness for your diagrams. You can adjust the spacing around the overcrossing by changing the `1.5`.

[image]

To make this work, draw the under-segments first. Then use `\draw[overcross]` or `\draw[overcross, double=red]` for the overcrossings. Note that this means splitting up segments into pieces. I set the `in` and `out` angles to make them look smooth.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{overcross/.style={double, line width=1.5, white, double=#1, double distance=\knotwidth},
    overcross/.default=black}
\tikzset{midarr/.style={decoration={markings,mark={at position .5 with {\arrow{>}}}},postaction={decorate}}}

\newcommand{\knotwidth}{.8pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=\knotwidth]
\draw (0,2) to[out=90, in=90] (-2,2);
\draw[red] (0,1.5) to[out=180, in=105] (-.25,.75);
\draw[red, midarr] (0,0) to[out=65, in=-105] (.25,.75);
\draw[overcross, double=red] (-1.75,1.9) to[out=180, in=90] (-2.2,1.3);
\draw[overcross] (0,2) circle[radius=1];
\draw[overcross] (-2,2) to[out=-90, in=-90] (0,2);
\draw[overcross, double=red] (.25,.75) to[out=75, in=0] (0,1.5);
\draw[overcross, double=red] (0,0) to[out=180, in=0] (-1.75,1.9);
\draw[red, midarr] (-2.2,1.3) to[out=-90, in=180] (0,0);
\draw[red] (-.25,.75) to[out=-75, in=115] (0,0);
\fill[red] (0,0) circle[radius=.05];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The overcross style is essentially what the knots package does, except that it works out which bits are the over/under strands so that you don't have to input all of the coordinates by hand.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32125/86 for the original inspiration.

Comment: Thank you, too!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example where to draw the arrows I just drew each loop one half at a time, and to generate the intersections I conveniently ordered the drawing of each element.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (1.1,-1.4);
\coordinate (B) at (-0.2,-0.1);
\coordinate (C) at (1.1,-0.4);
\draw (1,0) + (180:20pt) arc (180:245:20pt);
\draw[red] (B) to[out=180,in=175] (A);
\draw[white,line width=2.5pt] (0.3,0) ellipse (20pt and 10pt);
\draw (0.3,0) ellipse (20pt and 10pt);
\draw[red] (C) to[out=180, in=130] (A);
\draw[white,line width=2.5pt] (1,0) + (160:20pt) arc (160:-115:20pt);
\draw (1,0) + (-115:20pt) arc (-115:180:20pt);
\draw[white,line width=2.5pt] (A) + (156:10pt)  to[out=135,in=0] (B);
\draw[->,red] (A) to[out=175,in=0] (B);
\draw[white,line width=2.5pt] (A) to[out=50,in=0] (C);
\draw[->,red] (A) to[out=50,in=0] (C);
\filldraw [red] (A) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output from the code]