# Drawing knots with 8 crossings and labels

Tags: floats, pdftex, pstricks, diagrams, curve-fitting

So for a project, I have to draw the knot diagrams of all alternating knots with up to 8 crossings and label the regions bounded by the knots. For knots with up to 7 crossings, I used PSTricks, pst-knots package, but unfortunately, it doesn't include ones with 8 crossings. I did draw out the 8 crossing knots myself using beziers, but the change in style and neatness is noticeable. Is there an alternative package/method that wouldn't require redrawing all the knots?

Alternatively, since someone will suggest importing the knots as images, is there a way to place labels over images in LaTex?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17181/packages-for-creating-knot-diagrams and  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16897/how-to-make-nice-braids-diagrams of interest? For the last part: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz

Comment: Why not have a look at the code in the `pst-knot` package, i.e. the file `pst-knot.sty`, and try to adapt the code there.  If you run latex on a file using `pst-knot` the log file will give the complete path to locate this style file.

Comment: Actually the knot code is in `pst-psm.pro` which is read at the `dvips` stage.  It is located under `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/dvips/pst-knot/pst-psm.pro` on my system.  In that file you will find things like `/knot-7-6` followed by points described in polar coordinates and then the path specified with outgoing angles and over/under crossings.

Comment: Okay, I will give that a try and get back to you. Thanks, Andrew. And should that fail, Torbjorn's links look promising. Thanks for the suggestions.