# Availability of new braids package

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have been using both braid and knot packages. I have seen that a new braid package is available here but not in CTAN. Are there any projects to submit the new one to CTAN? One can always download it from here but it is annoying to use a "private" package in collaborative work or when uploading to arXiv. Thanks for your work.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a question (and there is no link to the package that you mean)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! I think that @DavidCarlisle must mean that your question is off-topic for this site because we cannot know if there are any plans afoot to submit a new or updated package to CTAN. (At least, in some cases somebody might know but that is by chance, as it were, rather than a feature of the site's knowledge base as such.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks a question about a package which cannot reasonably expect an answer on this site. (We can't know the plans people have to upload things to CTAN in the typical case.)

Answer (score 1):

The package is originated from a question here [How to make nice braids diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16897/how-to-make-nice-braids-diagrams) and our [Andrew Stacey (Loop Space)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/loop-space) is the author. And it is also [on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/braids). So you can install it via the usual ways.

We also have [a blog post](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/the-braids-package) about it. You can either comment there or email him about an update on CTAN.

Comment: I apologize for the maybe unnecessary noise. I know the package in CTAN but I discovered  [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/files) a version with more features (e.g., the size of the gap in the under-overcrossings). I will comment it in the blog.