# Packages for string diagrams

Tags: packages, diagrams, big-list

What TeX packages exist specifically for drawing string diagrams, e.g. like these:

[image: Zigzag-identity]

(or with similar styles)?

Comment: "knot diagrams" might also be a useful concept here.  (one possibility: [How to make nice braids diagrams](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16897/579); i hove no personal experience with this, hence a comment, not an answer.)

Comment: What have you tried or looked at? What if the answer is that there are not any? That is, the diagram is pretty simple and pretty generic, frankly, so why would somebody create a special strings package to draw it rather than using one of the general tools available which can draw this and many other things easily?

Comment: @cfr I think obviously because some people want to draw *a lot* of those and want to draw diagrams that are also more complicated than the above, e.g. give a complete proof that every adjunction induces a monad in string diagram language.

Comment: what was the best option you found ? I would like to add colors to those diagrams as well

Comment: @nicolas I draw them in TikZ directly. It's not as bad as I expected it to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tikz package (https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/TikZ_package) would appear to be sufficiently powerful to do what you request.

I have not tried this approach, but the link is live.

I hope that this helps.